# Connected components of undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Suppose I have an undirected graph G with vertices v1...vn and edges. Right now it is in adjacency list representation.

For every time moment a have as input some subset of vertices that are "active" at this moment. And I need to find all connected components in this subset of vertices for that time moment.

Right now I've implemented this using union-find data structure like this:

```
initialize sets for every active vertex so that every vertex has itself as "representative" (also called "parent")

for every active vertex v
   for all neighbours of v in G v_neighbour
      if v_neighbour is active
          union set of v and set of v_neighbour
```

It's should work ok, but I want to know if there is a more optimal approach to that? 
And what is the running time of that algorithm? O(N*M)?

Answer (score 3):

A [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) that restarts once a connected component is exhausted can easily find all connected components in undirected graph in `O(V+E)`

```
connectedComponentNumber= 0
While there is a node that was not discovered yet:
    connectedComponentNumber= connectedComponentNumber+ 1
    v = some vertex that was not discovered yet
    vertices = BFS(v) //all vertices connected to v
    set all nodes in vertices as belong to connected component connectedComponentNumber
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the suggestion. I'm implementing iterative DFS right now. It should be assymptotically faster. But I want to stress out the point, that the another programmer used some kind of DFS (while not very optimized) with recursion and it was much worse than my implementation. But I think that non recursive optimized version should work just fine.

Comment: @user1685095 Recursion or not, it's linear time. Whether you use the OS stack or a custom stack data structure should make no real difference in practice. Maybe there is another problem with that implementation, e.g. how the set of visited vertices or the graph itself is represented.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add one thing to the above reply that if you are finding active vertex in adjacency list representation it will increase V number of steps so running time time will increase to O(V^3).which can take constant time if we maintain another data structure for this.